# Drive window around screen with keypad

Tags: window

I am aware of the various shortcuts for resizing and placing a window in a particular location, but I would like to know if there is any software or method out there for driving a window around to an arbitrary location using the keypad as if you were driving a mouse around the screen that was dragging the window.

Similar to how in a lot of programs (Google Docs, Libre Office etc.) you can move an image by dragging with the mouse or CTRL+(SHIFT)+ARROW (optional precision mode).

Example:
You want to line two floating windows up horizontally but are not precise enough with the mouse, CTRL+???+ARROW

Comment: You mean like turning off the NumLock (which may not work as arrow keys), then pressing `Alt+Space, M` to move a window?

Comment: Is it too trivial to post as an answer and mark answered? I'm still a bit new to participating in stack exchange

Comment: I just wrote you a quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard strokes to achieve that in moving the window is as follows:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd> for Move, then you can use your arrow keys to move the window where ever you want.  Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to stop the move.

Hope this helps!